# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ats' of undefined

Tags: angular, typeerror

I'm building a project using Angular and whenever I change routes I'm getting this error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ats' of undefined` in console but the app is not crashing
and I don't have anything in the project called 'ats'.

Anybody has an idea on why this is happening?

This is my routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowseComponent } from './browse/browse.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'browse', component: BrowseComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[This is the error from the Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK1Nr.png)

Comment: show code to us

Comment: @reemObeid share code with attached image so that we can start find solution

Comment: I don't have anything called ats in the code. The error is only showing in the Chrome console.

Comment: I just shared an image of the error and my router module code

Comment: your code is minified/uglified, so the stacktrace is not readable. Can you run the app in dev mode, instead of prod mode ?

Comment: The issue might be in your component file. Are you trying to access any key named `ats` anywhere in your component?

Comment: I have nothing called `ats` anywhere